# How to use same database for a html based fanpage and php based site?

Tags: php, html, database, facebook, joomla

I tend to place a sign up form on facebook like on the website that is being developed for it. The site is developed by using php and Joomla. The fanpage is created using HTML and CSS. The site has a sign up area. I tend to put a similar (best if it is same) sign up area on facebook fanpage. Is there anyway that I can use the same data base to store both of them?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily acheived using an iframe tab on your Facebook page, because it's inside the iframe the page you're referencing can refresh without refreshing the parent meaning you can post form data easily, remove to use target="_self" to make sure that this works as expected. Here is more information about it:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/

Additionally due to width restrictions you may want to utilise ?tmpl=component on your Joomla website for ease.

Here are some loose instructions, I would give you a link to a podcast but Facebook application manager has just been completely overhauled so none of the tutorials I found are relevant, here goes:

1) Goto http://www.facebook.com/developers - It will ask for permissions press "accept"

2) then goto http://developers.facebook.com/apps

3) Click "create new app" in the top RH corner

4) Enter a name for your app in the popup, and agree to the terms (you may be asked to fill in a captcha afterwards).

5) Scroll to the bottom of the new page, and click on "Page tab"

6) Fill in the 4 fields, edit URL isn't necessary it can just point at your main url. https is a good to have as a lot of people use Facebook through https.

7) Press "save changes"

8) In the left hand column click on "view app profile page"

9) Then on the new page in the left hand column click on "add to my page"

10) Pick your page from the popup that appears.

11) goto your existing page, click on edit page and you will see the option to create a new tab using your iframe application.

Let me know if you need more details but these simple instructions should get you most of the way accompanied with the Facebook doc I posted above.